# How to convert json string into specified hashtable format with 5.1 powershell version?

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to convert json string into desired format of hashtable with powershell 5.1 version.

Used this code to convert json into hashtable but getting the o/p in the below mentioned format. How to convert this json into specified format of hashtable ?

**My code :**

```
    function ConvertTo-Hashtable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('hashtable')]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject
    )

    process {
        ## Return null if the input is null. This can happen when calling the function
        ## recursively and a property is null
        if ($null -eq $InputObject) {
            return $null
        }

        ## Check if the input is an array or collection. If so, we also need to convert
        ## those types into hash tables as well. This function will convert all child
        ## objects into hash tables (if applicable)
        if ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $InputObject -isnot [string]) {
            $collection = @(
                foreach ($object in $InputObject) {
                    ConvertTo-Hashtable -InputObject $object
                }
            )

            ## Return the array but don't enumerate it because the object may be pretty complex
            Write-Output -NoEnumerate $collection
        } elseif ($InputObject -is [psobject]) { ## If the object has properties that need enumeration
            ## Convert it to its own hash table and return it
            $hash = @{}
            foreach ($property in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties) {
                $hash[$property.Name] = ConvertTo-Hashtable -InputObject $property.Value
            }
            $hash
        } else {
            ## If the object isn't an array, collection, or other object, it's already a hash table
            ## So just return it.
            $InputObject
        }
    }
}
```

**json :**

```
$json = '[
  {
    "type": "IP",
    "Fields": [
      {
        "Column": "FileHash",
        "Id": "Address"
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

**Actual Format with my code:**

```
Name                           Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
Fields                   {System.Collections.Hashtable}                                                           
type                     IP
```

**Desired Format :**

```
 Key   : type
 Value : IP
 Name  : type


 Key   : Fields
 Value : {FileHash}
 Name  : Fields
```

Comment: The hash table is under the VALUE property.

Comment: @jdweng .. I'm newbie to powershell .. Can you please help me out to get the hashtable in desired o/p

Comment: What is the difference between `Key:` and `Name:`?

Comment: Actually tried converting the same json with powershell 7.1 version using  $json | ConvertFrom-Json  -AsHashTable . The o/p resulted in the format which I've mentioned in desired format. So, trying to replicate the same using 5.1 version manually since it does not have the in built -AsHashTable function

Comment: I found the posting which you used and got same results.  Just Add : $hashTable.Fields which will print the hash table.